# ExtJS6: Second instance of TreeStore has no grandchildren

Tags: extjs, extjs6

ExtJS6: Second instance of TreeStore has no grandchildren.

I have a class, MyStore, which inherits from `TreeStore`.
Then, I created an instance of MyStore to be displayed in a `treepanel`.
So far so good.
Then, I created another instance of MyStore to be displayed in another `treepanel`.
Here comes the problem: the second `treepanel` does not have grandchild. All it has are it's root node and it's root node's children.

How do I code this so that the 2nd (and succeeding) instance of `TreeStore` will have grandchildren?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ehq

```
Ext.define('MyStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        text: 'This is the root node',
        children: [
            {
                text: 'Food',
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                {
                    text: 'Cake',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Ice cream',
                    leaf: true
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'Toys',
                expanded: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        text: 'Ball',
                        leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Bat',
                        leaf: true
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.widget('treepanel',{
    title: 'first tree panel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: new MyStore()
});

Ext.widget('treepanel',{
    title: 'second tree panel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: new MyStore()
});

Ext.widget('panel', {
    html: 'What happend to the "Food" and "Toys" of the second tree panel? Why did they loose their children?',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
});
```

Comment: The data isn't copied, you would need to modify your code so it returns a new data instance.

Comment: Return a new data instance? Please enlighten me more. I believe I'm already creating a new data instance via `new MyStore()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Fiddle:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hti

```
Ext.define('MyStore',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore'
    });
    var store1 = Ext.create('MyStore',{
       extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            text: 'This is the root node',
            children: [
                {
                    text: 'Food',
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                    {
                        text: 'Cake',
                        leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Ice cream',
                        leaf: true
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: 'Toys',
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                        {
                            text: 'Ball',
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Bat',
                            leaf: true
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });
    var store2 = Ext.create('MyStore',{
       extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            text: 'This is the root node',
            children: [
                {
                    text: 'Food',
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                    {
                        text: 'Cake',
                        leaf: true
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Ice cream',
                        leaf: true
                    }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: 'Toys',
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                        {
                            text: 'Ball',
                            leaf: true
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Bat',
                            leaf: true
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });

    Ext.widget('treepanel',{
        title: 'first tree panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: store1
    });

    Ext.widget('treepanel',{
        title: 'second tree panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        store: store2
    });

    Ext.widget('panel', {
        html: 'What happend to the "Food" and "Toys" of the second tree panel? Why did they loose their children?',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    });
```

Comment: thanx for your answer but your solution isn't feasible to my current project which has about a dozen `TreeStore`. Duplicating data is not the way to go.